# Where Like statement to select records with specific tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table looks something like this:

```
id | title         | tags
1  | I like things | 9,3,7,10
2  | Stuff about i | 12,3,7,10
3  | Overly loaded | 1,3,4,5
4  | Never ever AT | 12,10
4  | Forever alone | 9
```

*Note: the names were made up, they're only for illustration purposes*

Things about the tags:

- The numbers represent the numeric ID of a given tag, ranging from `0` to `12`
- `1`, `9` and `12` will always be the first tag in this list, followed by the rest of the tags in a sorted order from low to high
- An entry can also have only one tag, `1`, `9` or `12`.

I want to add a filter feature, which allows the user to filter the list using these tags. Let's ignore the client-side part, and only care about what we recieve.

Let's say, the script receives the following input (which is always sorted): `"3,4,9"`

Then, I would like to pass this to a MySQL query in order to retrieve the matching items. The site also has a pagination feature, but I'm only saying this because it may affect the order of the statements, it's not important otherwise. It just adds a `LIMIT` statement at the end.

Putting all escaping and what not aside, the query I tried to use was

```
SELECT * FROM `$tablename` WHERE tags LIKE '%$input%' ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 0,10
```

But this - of course - didn't work. I gave me this nice little error message, saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%3,4,9%' ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 0,10' at line 1 in **script.php** on line **n**

I would like to know how to alter this query in order to be able to properly filter the results, even if it takes an extra function to append multiple `LIKE` statements together.

Comment: So, just to be clear, there is a single field in the database that stores multiple values, separated by a comma?

Comment: I don't think this approach will work well. 

First, good database design requires separate fields for each piece of data. You want the data to be "atomic."  

Second, this is not how the LIKE function works - with this SQL statement, it will search for the exact string coming from $input, but with other characters before or after it, where you have placed the %. You would need $input sorted with the 1, 9, or 12 first, and then the LIKE statement would just need a single % at the end.

Comment: @DJDavid98 you'll probably want to convert that to a separate table with a row per title/tag combination.  That would be much simpler to query.  And faster, too, since the way you have it set up now indexes can't be used.

Comment: @GrandmasterB I understand your point, but I would not want to do that unless it's impossible or way too complex to do it with the table being the way it is now.

Comment: Its not impossible the way you have it now.  But if is far more trouble than it's probably worth.  A second table will work much better in the long run.  And, dont discount what I said about indexes.  If you keep things the way they are, if you end up with 10,000 rows in your database, the database will have to search *every* row in the database when searching by tags.  If you had it broken into two tables, it could use indexes to very quickly find the entries for those tags.

Comment: @GrandmasterB You're right. I think I'll go with the separate table option. Not sure if I should delete this question or not, since the real answer isn't really the answer to the main question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this broad question has been asked before here. I don't know if I can find a duplicate right now, but "should I store many items of data in a single column" always comes back "no"!

Comment: @halfer I'll keep it then.

Comment: @DJDavid98 if you absolutely had to keep it like this, you could pad the tag id's with zeroes to a fixed size, like 00009 instead of just 9.  Then you could reliably search for 00009.  But I'm glad you decided to try the 2nd table.  I think that will do you much better in the long run.

Comment: @halfer Good idea, but now I've waited too long, i.e. more than 30 seconds...

Comment: @larsAnders, ha! Yeah, you sometimes need to be quick on the draw here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE tags LIKE '%$input%'`

Will only work when the list of input tags is found within the tags string.  "3,4,9" is not like "3,4,5,9"

You have a denormalized structure, which is causing you problems, one row per tag value is what you should implement.

The alternative is to break apart the input string and use multiple `OR LIKE` statements:

```
WHERE tags LIKE '%input1%'
   OR tags LIKE '%input2%'
    ....
```

Then you have to deal with the issue of `1` matching to `11`, which means concatenating commas on the front and back of each side of the `LIKE` statement, or padding with some value.  The workaround becomes an ugly beast that's far less efficient than fixing the underlying design problem.

Comment: Nice summary, thanks! I will just use a separate table.

Answer (score 2):

I know this won't be the accepted answer, but because there may be cases where changing the database structure may not be possible, I thought I'd put this out there as a precise answer to the question.

Given the constraints you've stated, and assuming PHP is your control language (since the question is tagged with PHP), I would build the SQL statement using PHP:

```
<?php
// assuming $tags contains your comma-delimited tags
$tags_array = explode(',',$tags);
$where = 'where true';
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tags_array);$i++) {
  switch($tags_array[$i]) {
    case '1':
      $where .= " and tags LIKE '1%' and tags NOT LIKE '12%'";
      break;
    case '9':
    case '12':
      $where .= " and tags LIKE '" . $tags_array[$i] . "%'";
      break;
    default:
      $where .= " and tags LIKE '%," . $tags_array[$i] . "%'";
      break;
  }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tablename` " . $where . " ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT 0,10";
?>
```

Having said that, I agree with everyone commenting above: it's much better to get the data model right in the database.